# Spiting array of integers into multiple integer arrays depending on specific condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to split a single integer arrays into multiple integer arrays depending on specific condition using Neo4j Cypher query. Following is the example:

```
Input - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Output - [1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9] ==> Split the array as soon as the sum of elements is greater than 8
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Cypher query?

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this in Cypher, but the code can be a bit intimidating :-).

For example, this query:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] AS input
RETURN REDUCE(s = {sum:0, res:[]}, x IN input | CASE
  WHEN s.sum + x > 8 THEN CASE
    WHEN s.sum = 0 THEN {sum:0, res:s.res+[[x]]}
    ELSE {sum:0, res:s.res[..-1]+[s.res[-1]+x]} END
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN s.sum = 0 THEN {sum:s.sum+x, res:s.res+[[x]]}
    ELSE {sum:s.sum+x, res:s.res[..-1]+[s.res[-1]+[x]]} END
  END
).res AS result
```

produces this result:

```
╒═══════════════════════════╕
│"result"                   │
╞═══════════════════════════╡
│[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9]]│
└───────────────────────────┘
```

Note: with the above query, the last sublist will always contain the remainder of the input list, and its sum does not necessarily exceed 8. If the sum of the last sublist must also exceed 8, then this modified query:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8] AS input, 8 AS bound
WITH bound, REDUCE(s = {sum:0, res:[]}, x IN input | CASE
  WHEN s.sum + x > bound THEN CASE
    WHEN s.sum = 0 THEN {sum:0, res:s.res+[[x]]}
    ELSE {sum:0, res:s.res[..-1]+[s.res[-1]+x]} END
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN s.sum = 0 THEN {sum:s.sum+x, res:s.res+[[x]]}
    ELSE {sum:s.sum+x, res:s.res[..-1]+[s.res[-1]+[x]]} END
  END
).res AS res
RETURN CASE
  WHEN REDUCE(t=0, y IN res[-1] | t+y) > bound THEN res
  ELSE res[..-1] END AS result
```

produces this result:

```
╒═══════════════════════╕
│"result"               │
╞═══════════════════════╡
│[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]│
└───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Neat that you can do this with Cypher alone. Alternately, if this is a frequent operation and you want it a bit more compact, you could create your own [user defined function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/) to do the heavy lifting for you.